# Accelerated mobile pages link to css file

Tags: css, mobile, amp-html

I am trying to link to css file :

```
<link href="/semanticui/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Opening chrome in `#development=1` mode to test my page for amp. I am getting this error :

```
The attribute 'href' in tag 'link rel=stylesheet for fonts' is set to the invalid value '/semanticui/semantic.css'.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

External stylesheets are not permitted.  Use inline styling to avoid the additional request for css.

More info can be found at:  https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-format.md#stylesheets

> Authors may add custom styles to a document using a single `<style amp-custom>` tag in the head of the document.

Comment: please check this link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199925/external-style-sheet-is-not-working-in-amp-pages

Answer (score 8):

i am using php pages so I do the following to add my custom css page, so i can seperate it and also include in all pages so changing only once etc.

```
<style amp-custom>
  <?php readfile( getcwd() . "/css/main.min.css"); ?>
</style>
```

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199925/external-style-sheet-is-not-working-in-amp-pages

Comment: sorry did not get a ping on this comment, are yu asking still for help??

Answer (score 1):

Any styling to the page and its elements is done using common CSS properties. Style elements using class or element selectors in an inline stylesheet in the , called `<style amp-custom>`

here is sample code:

```
<style amp-custom>
  /* any custom style goes here */
  body {
    background-color: white;
  }
  amp-img {
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<style amp-custom>
    <?php echo file_get_contents(STYLESHEETPATH.'/style.css'); ?>
</style>
```